# Wordpress wp_create_nonce solution

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have two metaboxes and added to lines like this with diffrent names, and I could update the values ones, but now it displays the old values but can't update into the database, somehow it still displays the old content

OLD

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ).'" />
```

And when I saw that it's not working anymore I modifided to

```
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
```

I thought the problem was from here, but still not working.

Code to long, please see it  here: http://pastebin.com/rXdYc221

So can someone see the problem?

Comment: It looks like these lines are the problem:   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce') )
    return $post_id;

  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_meta_box_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
```

Should be:

> if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce') )